# Paste function quote RMySQL

Tags: sql, r, rmysql

I'm trying to execute a loop from a matrix but It doesn't work; here is :

```
library(RMySQL)

for(i in 1:nrow(m_tblunif))
{
    Nm <- noquote(m_tblunif[[i,2]])
    PreNm <-noquote(m_tblunif[[i,3]])
    DateN<-noquote(m_tblunif[[i,4]])
    Idd <- noquote(m_tblunif[[i,9]])
    Flag <- noquote(m_tblunif[[i,10]])
    Critic <- noquote(m_tblunif[[i,11]])
data2<-paste("UPDATE membres_unif SET IDD=$Idd, 
    FLAG=$Flag, CRITIC=$Critic WHERE Nm=\"$Nm\",
    AND PreNm=\"$PreNm\", AND DateN=\"$DateN\"");
    sql_update_tbl_ds <- fn$dbSendQuery(dbconnection, data2)
}
```

Edit: The problemn is that, R recognize all the line but i have this error message that i think come from MySQL Server : Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND PreNm="MADINE", AND DateN="01/01/1961"' at line 1

I've tried different possibilities but I get always this error.
Please is it possible look what's wrong ? 
And how is it possible to execute this loop with few lines ie like this :

```
 data2<-paste("UPDATE membres_unif SET IDD=noquote(m_tblunif[[i,9]]), 
    FLAG=noquote(m_tblunif[[i,10]]), CRITIC=noquote(m_tblunif[[i,11]]) WHERE Nm=\"noquote(m_tblunif[[i,2]])\",
    AND PreNm=\"noquote(m_tblunif[[i,3]])\", AND DateN=\"$DateN\"");
    sql_update_tbl_ds <- fn$dbSendQuery(dbconnection, data2)
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: "it doesn't work" -- if you're more specific, it would make it easier for people to help you

Comment: Ok you're wright, the problemn is that, R recognize all the line but i have this error message that i think come from MySQL Server :
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND PreNm="MADINE", AND DateN="01/01/1961"' at line 1

Comment: I've seen the error for the first part i've inserted the coma ","  after "MADINE",.
The 2nd problem remain even if I remove the coma "," ie improve perfomance of the loop 's performance.